# Want to create WPF solution in MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am newbie in WPF world and want to create a solution where I want to write MVVM program using C# and XAML to perform some simple computations.

The `MainWindow xaml` has an named outer grid `View`.

The xaml code behind (`MainWindow.xaml.cs`) may only contain a constructor

which sets the `View.DataContext` to an instance of a new `ViewModel` class.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
     public MainWindow()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         View.DataContext = new ViewModel();
     }
 }
```

two result textboxes containing : C = A + B, and D = A * B.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but... Have you tried anything ? We aren't here to solve your homework

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez, Sorry for this. I need some guidance to start this. Please guide me how start. I am very new to WPF so please forgive me if I am not allowed to post this kind of things then.

Comment: Look into Interactivity and the `EventToCommand`. This will give you an idea on how to handle the inputs in a MvvM way, you can also use the event in code behind (**as long as it invokes the `ViewModel`'s Command**). I pewrsonally like to initiate `DataContext` in xaml and not code behind. Also show us your xaml that "`View`" worries me.

Comment: There are many ways to implement what you describe, but maybe you should honestly learn the basics knowledge of WPF. Because these are very basic knowledge. It’s more valuable for you to learn in a structured way than to ask questions in Stack Overflow to get a ready-made code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define four properties in the `ViewModel` class, `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` and implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) interface.

`C` and `D` should be read-only and you should raise the `PropertyChanged` for these whenever `A` or `B` changes. Here is a basic example that should give you the idea:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _a;
    public int A
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set { _a = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(C)); }
    }

    private int _b;
    public int B
    {
        get { return _b; }
        set { _b = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(C)); }
    }

    public int C => _a + _b;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "") =>
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

}
```

The background change can be implemented by handling the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events for the `TextBoxes` and set the `Background` property of the window to a `Brush`. This functionality is purely view-related and should not be implemented in the view model.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a home work question, so I'll give you some general pointers rather than a complete solution.

Your XAML needs 4 TextBoxes (although C and D are readonly, so they could be TextBlocks)

Your ViewModel needs 4 properties, which are bound to the Text property of these boxes. In the setter for A and B, calculate the values for C and D. The ViewModel will also need a BackgroundColor property.

Use Interaction.Triggers (from Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll) on the text boxes to pass the events to your ViewModel, and change the BackgroundColor property.

Finally bind the Background property of the window to the BackgroundColor property.

You should be able to look up examples (and explainations) for each of these steps.